# Add a property for each instance of a class in GSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

```
class Human {
   String name;
}

class Student extends Human {
   String college;
}

class Worker extends Human {
   String workPlace;
}
```

Suppose I want to serialize this using GSON.

Is it possible to add a pair `"type" : "student"` for each serialized `Student` instance (just as if `type` was a field of the class)? Similarly, add `"type" : "worker"` for each `Worker` instance?

---

A related question regards deserialization of such JSONS:
[Deserialize recursive polymorphic class in GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327670/deserialize-recursive-polimorphic-class)

Comment: i think you want to make a generic class with type as variable check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/19173640/2334391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by gson custom  JsonSerializer like this

```
public class HumanSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Human> {

 @Override
public JsonElement serialize(final Human human, final Type type, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
             final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
             if(human instanceof Human)
                 json.addProperty("type", "Human");
             if(human instanceof Worker)
                 json.addProperty("type", "Worker");
             if(human instanceof Student)
                 json.addProperty("type", "Student");

         json.addProperty("name", human.getName());
        return json;
    }
}
```

finally you have to register your classes and then serialize it

```
final GsonBuilder  gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Human.class,new  HumanSerializer());
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Worker.class,new  HumanSerializer());
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Student.class,new  HumanSerializer());
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

**Output**

```
 gson.toJson(new Worker("adam", "workplace"));
 gson.toJson(new Human("Jhon"));

{"type":"Worker","name":"adam"}
{"type":"Human","name":"Jhon"}
```

Comment: Any idea how to deserialize it then?

Comment: via gson custom deserializer you can get the type value. you have HumanAdapater also implements the JsonDeserilize finally populate your object and return it

Comment: can you provide an example so your answer is complete?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327670/deserialize-recursive-polimorphic-class