# Can't handle json tree list using TypeToken + generics with Gson in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, android, gson

I have got the json structure as below:

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "total": 3,
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "brand",
      "id": "15243937043340",
      "company": {
        "object": "company",
        "id": "956936000",
        "name": "ABC"
      },
      "name": "Kindle",
      "images": [
        "http://www.spacecentrestorage.com/assets/uploads/General/SCS-Slide02-Commercial.jpg"
      ]
    },
    {
      "object": "brand",
      "id": "15243937043340",
      "company": {
        "object": "company",
        "id": "956936000",
        "name": "ABC"
      },
      "name": "Kindle",
      "images": [
        "http://www.spacecentrestorage.com/assets/uploads/General/SCS-Slide02-Commercial.jpg"
      ]
    },
    {
     "object": "brand",
      "id": "15243937043340",
      "company": {
        "object": "company",
        "id": "956936000",
        "name": "ABC"
      },
      "name": "Kindle",
      "images": [
        "http://www.spacecentrestorage.com/assets/uploads/General/SCS-Slide02-Commercial.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "associated": {}
}
```

And this is my Gson data class mapping :

```
data class Response (

        @SerializedName("object")
        val obj: String,
         val total: Int,
         val data: List<*>,
         val associated: Response
)


data class Brand (

        @SerializedName("object")
        val obj: String,
        val id: String,
         val name: String,
         val images: List<String>,
         val company: Company
)

   data class Company (

        @SerializedName("object")
        val obj: String,
        val id: String,
         val name: String 
)
```

When it comes to extracting the tree as above, I find returned data string becomes Malformed Json and gives MalformedJsonException on $[0].companies.null

I have read about the [recursive deserialisation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327670/deserialize-recursive-polymorphic-class-in-gson) but it is not working in my case. I resort to deserialise as below , using original method, it causes errors

```
  val response = gson.fromJson(queryResult , Response::class.java)
        println("result 2 : $response" )
        val dataString = response.data.toString()
        println("result 3 : $dataString" )
        val brands  = Gson().fromJson(dataString, Array<Brand>::class.java).toMutableList()
        println("result 4 : $brands" )
```

I would like to ask :

1. If returning json component to string, shall all the indents and symbols " be erased ?
2. To extract all associated object of the elements of the list of objects, what precautions do I have to take for deserialising list of objects using Gson ?

Comment: did . you get a working solution

Answer (score 0):

If you set the type parameter of the `data` list in `Response` to `Brand` GSON knows how to deserialise the items of the list.

```
data class Response (

    @SerializedName("object")
    val obj: String,
    val total: Int,
    val data: List<Brand>, 
    val associated: Response

)
```

Using this there is no need to parse the items of the list again and you can get all `brands` like this:

```
val response = Gson().fromJson(queryResult , Response::class.java)
val dataList = response.data
print("brands: " )
dataList.forEach { println(it) }
```

Comment: Let me tell you clearly, response data can be every data class instead of Brand

Comment: So every item of a list can have a different type? Or is it that every list can have a different generic type, but the items in the list have the same type for a given list?

Comment: The attribute Data can be a list of generic object or a generic object . Object can be every data class I can define . I am figuring out the way to using custom data class extended by the base data object. Do you have any clues for that? Ok